# Fragment button affecting other instances of the same fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a button that adds an instance of a fragment, `ActivityFragment`, when pressed. There is an `edit_button` in the fragment that, when pressed, changes the `activity_text` textview in the fragment. However, when multiple instances of `ActivityFragment` are added, any `edit_button` pressed in any fragment will only affect the first `ActivityFragment` added. I believe this is happening because each fragment shares the same id, but would there be any way to get around this so that each `edit_button` only affects the fragment that it is in, preferably without changing the fragment id upon creation?

Here is the `Activity Fragment` xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/activity_fragment">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Edit Activity"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/checkbox"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/checkbox"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/edit_button"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/edit_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="editActivity"
        android:text="Edit Activity"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/checkbox"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my `MainActivity.java` with the `ActivityFragment` class. The onClick method for the `edit_button` is at the very bottom:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public static class ActivityFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
        container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment, container, 
            false);
        }
    }

    public void addActivity(View view) {
        ActivityFragment fragment1 = new ActivityFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1).commit();
    }

    //This is the editButton method
    public void editActivity(View view) {
        TextView activityText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_text);
        activityText.setText("success");
    }

}
```

*This is my first time posting a question, sorry if I'm doing anything incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're adding lots of fragments to your view. You haven't noticed that because all of them are equals to each other. I think you have to change this:

```
public void addActivity(View view) {
    ActivityFragment fragment1 = new ActivityFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1).commit();
}
```

to this:

```
public void addActivity(View view) {
    ActivityFragment fragment1 = new ActivityFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1).commit();
}
```

You have to remember that, when you're adding, all the views are appended and the findViewById will find the first one. And you can remove the *static* from the Fragment.

Comment: I'm relatively new to android, so sorry if I'm misunderstanding this, but the way I have my layout set up, each fragment is added to a scroll-able linearlayout, below the previously added fragment. I want the user to be able to add multiple fragments and then interact with each of them separately. Currently, I can add multiple fragments, and there is no problem with them being stacked over each other. When I use .replace, only on fragment can be displayed, as the previously added one is replaced.

Comment: I got it. So, please, take a look at [How to Create Lists and Cards](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) article from Android documentation. You're learning how to do basic things for now and this is cool, but if you're thinking in lists, you have to use RecyclerView to reach a more safe code. Finally, answering your question, you will have to use TAGs to name each view you add to a different name (maybe a counter to help you? view1, view2...) and to find the right view, you will use findViewByTag, from View class, got it?

Comment: my bad, use `findViewWithTag` instead

Answer (score 0):

By using this :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1).commit();
```

You are stacking up fragments one over the other. Change it to

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1).commit();
```

Comment: The way I have my layout set up, each fragment is added to a scroll-able linearlayout, below the previously added fragment. I want the user to be able to add multiple fragments and then interact with each of them separately. Currently, I can add multiple fragments, and there is no problem with them being stacked over each other. When I use .replace, only on fragment can be displayed, as the previously added one is replaced. The problem is that buttons pressed in new instances of the fragment only affect the fragment at the top of the linearlayout, not themselves.